# React Native, how to update async-storage immediately?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm making a simple drinking game. When a playing card shows, it's corresponding rule shows below it. I have a settings.js file where the rules are, and the user can see and modify the rules, and they update on the game.js file. I'm using async-storage to store the rules.

I wanted to add a button in the settings.js file, which would return the original rules when pressed. The only problem is, that the original rules don't update immediately on the settings screen. When the button is pressed the original rules do update on the game, but they update on the settings screen only when the user goes back in the game and then back in the settings screen.

The code for updating the rules:

```
initialState = async () => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('rule1', 'theoriginalrule1')
        ...
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('rule13', 'theoriginalrule13')
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
        }
}
```

I have the following line of code to update the async-storage when the screen is entered, but as said, it only works when the screen is re-entered:

```
componentDidMount() {
const { navigation } = this.props;
this.focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
    this.getData();
    });
}
```

Comment: It renders after a re-render because you're not calling at all this.getData() into the componentDidMount. You are just starting a listener, and it will call this.getData() only on next render.

Comment: @CevaComic Okey, I'm quite new with React Native, could you explain how to call the getData() into the componentDidMount in a way that it would render it immediately?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question here, not in a comment.

Try this :

```js
componentDidMount() {
const { navigation } = this.props;
this.getData();
this.focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
    this.getData();
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does the exact same thing, only updates after re-render.

Comment: In this case... I think you should use all that code inside componentWillMount(), or try a functional component which is much easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use ,

**State driven UI**

means your ui will change only when state is changed , now suppose you are changing your asyncStorage, using

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('rule1', 'theoriginalrule1')
```

so I would suggest your state will also update after updating your aysncStorage like.

```html
//Initial state
this.state = { score: 0 };

async storeValues(){
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('rule1', 'theoriginalrule1')
    let newScoreValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('rule1')
    this.setState({score:newScoreValue})
}

// UI will be like 

render(){
    return(<Text>{this.state.score}</Text>)
}
```